# Should we implement interfaces like ActionListener or not?

Tags: java, swing

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
public class foo extends JButton implements ActionListener
{
    public foo()
    {
        super();
        addActionListener(this);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        bar(e);
    }
}
```

When I compile something along these lines, NetBeans throws a minor error :

`Leaking in this constructor`
or `Passing Suspicious Parameter in this constructor`

So should we or should we not use such coding conventions? Is it better to use anonymous classes?

I would like to know the significance of this error.
I have learnt this usage from the Java Tutorials on Oracle Website. So, Is this a bad coding practice?

Comment: This isn't so much an issues with implementing `ActionListener` as it's a warning against using `this` in a object constructor, as the object could be in an uninitialised state which the object or method you are passing it to might rely on.  Personally, I would also ask the question, do you want to expose the `interface` methods to other callers. For example, there's nothing stopping anyone from calling your `actionPerformed` method and passing it erroneous data

Comment: Side note: it's a good idea to call `super(/* Constructor Parameters */);` on the first line of the constructor of many objects.

Comment: NetBeans*prints* a minor *warning.* What you do about it is up to you. Personally, after a lot of toing and froing, I prefer `ActionListeners` to do nothing else, i.e. be inner classes.